# Spring data MongoDB (aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Let's consider the following documents:

```
country{id="1", name="France", cities=[{detail="new_city"}, {from="Paris"}, {from="Lyon"} ]}
country{id="2", name="UK", cities=[{detail="new_city"}, {from="Paris"}, {from="London"}, {from="Liverpool"} ]}
```

If the user searches for "from"="Paris" and the cities array contains "from"="Paris", then the output will be:

```
country{id="1", name="France", cities={from="Paris"}}
country{id="2", name="UK", cities={from="Paris"}}
```

If the user searches for "from"="Los Angeles" and the cities array doesn't contain "from"="Los Angeles", then we must search for object in the cities array that contains "detail"="new_city", so the output will be:

```
country{id="1", name="France", cities={detail="new_city"}}
country{id="2", name="UK", cities={detail="new_city"}}
```

How can I perform this using aggregation?

SpringBoot version: spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb 2.7.3

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up a project at https://github.com/VonC/countrysearch

It includes [`src/main/java/com/example/countrysearch/service/CountryService.java`](https://github.com/VonC/countrysearch/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/countrysearch/service/CountryService.java), using an [`Aggregation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html)

The pipeline with the following steps:

1. **Filtered Cities Addition**: that filters cities based on whether their `from` field matches the `searchTerm`. The filtered array is then stored in a new field called `filteredCities`.
2. **Conditional Logic for Final Cities**: The pipeline checks whether `filteredCities` is empty (size is zero). If it is empty, a fallback occurs where the pipeline filters the cities based on the `detail` field set to `new_city`. The resulting array is stored in another new field called `finalCities`.
3. **Output Formatting**: The final operation in the pipeline projects (or selects) the fields that are required in the final output, such as `id`, `name`, and `finalCities`. The `finalCities` is renamed as `cities` in the final output.

```
   +----------------------+
   | Input Document       |
   +----------------------+
             |
             |
             v
 +------------------------+
 | Add 'filteredCities'    |  --->  Filter cities based on the 'from' field
 +------------------------+
             |
             |
             v
 +------------------------+
 | Conditional Logic      |  --->  Check if 'filteredCities' is empty; fallback to 'detail="new_city"'
 +------------------------+
             |
             |
             v
 +------------------------+
 | Output Formatting      |  --->  Project required fields ('id', 'name', 'finalCities')
 +------------------------+
             |
             |
             v
 +------------------------+
 | Final Output           |
 +------------------------+
```

#### Full `CountryService.java` Code

```java
package com.example.countrysearch.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.project;

import com.example.countrysearch.model.Country;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<Country> findCountriesByCity(String searchTerm) {

        // AggregationExpression for 'filteredCities'
        AggregationExpression filterCitiesExpression = ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("cities")
                .as("city")
                .by(ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("city.from").equalToValue(searchTerm));

        // First addFields operation to add 'filteredCities'
        AggregationOperation addFieldsFilteredCities = project("id", "name", "cities")
                .and(filterCitiesExpression)
                .as("filteredCities");

        // AggregationExpression for conditional logic for 'finalCities'
        AggregationExpression conditionalFinalCities = ConditionalOperators.when(
                ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf(
                        ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray("filteredCities")
                ).equalToValue(0)
        )
        .then(
            ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("cities")
            .as("city")
            .by(
                ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("city.detail").equalToValue("new_city")
            )
        )
        .otherwise("$filteredCities");

        // Second addFields operation to add 'finalCities'
        AggregationOperation addFieldsFinalCities = project("id", "name")
                .and(conditionalFinalCities).as("finalCities");

        // Final project operation to shape the output
        AggregationOperation projectFinal = project("id", "name")
                .and("finalCities").as("cities");

        // Build the aggregation pipeline
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                addFieldsFilteredCities,
                addFieldsFinalCities,
                projectFinal
        );

        // Execute the aggregation
        AggregationResults<Country> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "country", Country.class);

        return result.getMappedResults();
    }
}
```

---

In the `filterCitiesExpression`, what would be the syntax in the `.by()` method if I want to add another comparison, for example: `ComparisonOperators.Eq... AND ComparisonOperators.Ne...;`?

To add multiple comparisons in the `.by()` method, you can use [`BooleanOperators.And.and`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/BooleanOperators.And.html#and(java.lang.Object...)) to combine multiple conditions. The syntax would look something like this:

```java
AggregationExpression filterCitiesExpression = ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("cities")
    .as("city")
    .by(
        BooleanOperators.And.and(
            ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("city.from").equalToValue(searchTerm),
            ComparisonOperators.Ne.valueOf("city.someOtherField").notEqualToValue(someOtherValue)
        )
    );
```

This example will filter the array with objects where `city.from` is equal to `searchTerm` and `city.someOtherField` is not equal to `someOtherValue`.

---

> In the case where I need to add a filter to the cities array, ex: I want to prioritize populating cities with the object found:
>
> - a. `city.from="Paris" and city.population>1M`
> - b. Otherwise, only the object `city.from="Paris"`
> - c. And finally, if none of the above, `"city.detail"="new_city"`
>
> Currently, conditions b and c are implemented.
>
> - a takes precedence over b.
> - b takes precedence over c.
>
> To avoid: if, in the `cities` array, one document contains `"city.population" < 1000000`, and another document contains `"city.from" = "Paris"` without the information for `"city.population"`, then the newly formed array will contain conditions a) and b), when only condition b) should be present.

To prioritize populating the cities array with the conditions specified, you could implement a chain of conditional (`$cond`) statements. This will require an update to the `conditionalFinalCities` variable.

To achieve the behavior outlined (a > b > c), the pipeline must be restructured to sequentially check each condition, applying the next one only if the previous conditions do not yield any results.

Since filtering logic for condition "a" and condition "b" is not mutually exclusive (I.e. if one document in the `cities` array matches condition "b" (`"city.from" = "Paris"`) but lacks the `"city.population"` field, and another document meets condition "a" (`"city.from" = "Paris" and "city.population" > 1000000`), both will be included in the final array), that would violate the constraint that only the condition with the highest priority should prevail.

One way to fix this is to use additional stages in the aggregation pipeline to isolate documents that strictly meet condition "a" and disregard those that meet condition "b" but not "a".

```java
package com.example.countrysearch.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

import com.example.countrysearch.model.Country;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<Country> findCountriesByCity(String searchTerm) {
        AggregationExpression conditionAExpr = ConditionalOperators.when(
                BooleanOperators.And.and(
                        ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("city.from").equalToValue(searchTerm),
                        ComparisonOperators.Gt.valueOf("city.population").greaterThanValue(1000000)
                )
        ).thenValueOf("$$KEEP").otherwise(null);

        AggregationExpression conditionBExpr = ConditionalOperators.when(
                ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("city.from").equalToValue(searchTerm)
        ).thenValueOf("$$KEEP").otherwise(null);

        AggregationExpression conditionCExpr = ConditionalOperators.when(
                ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("city.detail").equalToValue("new_city")
        ).thenValueOf("$$KEEP").otherwise(null);

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                project("id", "name", "cities")
                        .and(ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("cities")
                                .as("city")
                                .by(conditionAExpr))
                        .as("conditionACities")
                        .and(ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("cities")
                                .as("city")
                                .by(conditionBExpr))
                        .as("conditionBCities")
                        .and(ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("cities")
                                .as("city")
                                .by(conditionCExpr))
                        .as("conditionCCities"),
                project("id", "name")
                        .and(
                                ConditionalOperators.when(
                                        ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf(
                                                ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray("conditionACities")
                                        ).equalToValue(0)
                                ).thenValueOf(
                                        ConditionalOperators.when(
                                                ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf(
                                                        ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray("conditionBCities")
                                                ).equalToValue(0)
                                        ).then("$conditionCCities").otherwise("$conditionBCities")
                                ).otherwise("$conditionACities")
                        ).as("finalCities")
        );

        AggregationResults<Country> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "country", Country.class);

        return result.getMappedResults();
    }
}
```

This version of `CountryService.java` uses additional aggregation stages to first check the size of `filteredCitiesForA` (i.e., whether any document strictly meets condition "a"). If no document meets condition "a", it then checks condition "b". Depending on these checks, the final array `finalCities` is populated accordingly.

Remember to include this new `filterForA` expression in your pipeline to replace the old one.
I have done so in [`CountryService.java`](https://github.com/VonC/countrysearch/blob/51164f6f3cf694147d21d94760817b7f5be1241b/src/main/java/com/example/countrysearch/service/CountryService.java#L22-L67), which compiles just fine.

Comment: First, thank you for your feedback. For field finalCities, can you tell me what "isEmpty()", " filter()" and "conditional()" corresponds to because it's not recognized (undefined methods)? Thank you

Comment: @AdamD I have updated the final code to only use Spring Data MongoDB's API.

Comment: Thanks, however I have an error.
I also tried to replace the size method with elemMatch but I still get the same type of error
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 16020 (Location16020): 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: Expression $size takes exactly 1 arguments. 2 were passed in.'

Comment: I believe the problem arises in the 'addFieldsFinalCities' aggregation: $project and $size stages.

Comment: @AdamD Working on it: https://github.com/VonC/countrysearch/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/countrysearch/service/CountryService.java

Comment: @AdamD I have rewritten the answer. Codespace project: https://stunning-trout-r4rwgq4qrcwxvr.github.dev/

Comment: Thank you again for your explanations. Can I ask you two more things:
1) In the filterCitiesExpression, what would be the syntax in the .by() method if I want to add another comparison, for example:
ComparisonOperators.Eq... AND ComparisonOperators.Ne...;

2) In the case where I need to add a filter to the cities array, ex:
I want to prioritize populating cities with the object found:
a) city.from="Paris" and city.population>1M
b) Otherwise only the object city.from="Paris"
c) And finally, if none of the above, "city.detail"="new_city" 
Currently, conditions b and c are implemented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255401/discussion-between-vonc-and-adam-d).